# How to save the changes in kivy for the next time

Tags: python, kivy

I have being trying to save the changes in kivy of dark mode and light mode so whenever a user selects a mode and open next time the mode will be the one which was selected. I was trying it with open() method but failed. Can anyone tell how to save these changes.

## Python File

```
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager,Screen
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window
import os


# making the screen full
Window.size =(1366, 168)
Window.fullscreen = True

# Variables
# Screens
class Screen1(Screen):
    pass

class Screen2(Screen):

    def mode(self, value):

        if value == 'Dark' or value == 'Default':

            # Screen 1
            self.manager.screens[0].ids.i1.source = 'Images\\dark\\t.jpg'
            self.manager.screens[0].ids.b1.background_normal = 'Images\\dark\\btn.jpg'
            self.manager.screens[0].ids.b2.background_normal = 'Images\\dark\\btn.jpg'
            self.manager.screens[0].ids.b3.background_normal = 'Images\\dark\\btn.jpg'
            self.manager.screens[0].ids.l1.color = 1, 1, 1, 1
            self.manager.screens[0].ids.b1.color = 1, 1, 1, 1
            self.manager.screens[0].ids.b2.color = 1, 1, 1, 1
            self.manager.screens[0].ids.b3.color = 1, 1, 1, 1
            # Screen 2
            self.ids.i1.source = 'Images\\dark\\bg.jpg'
            self.ids.b1.background_normal = 'Images\\dark\\btn.jpg'
            self.ids.b2.background_normal = 'Images\\dark\\btn.jpg'
            self.ids.s1.background_normal = 'Images\\dark\\btn.jpg'
            self.ids.l1.color = 1, 1, 1, 1
            self.ids.l2.color = 1, 1, 1, 1
            self.ids.l3.color = 1, 1, 1, 1
            self.ids.s1.color = 1, 1, 1, 1
            self.ids.b1.color = 1, 1, 1, 1
            self.ids.b2.color = 1, 1, 1, 1


        elif value == 'Light' :
            # Screen 1
            self.manager.screens[0].ids.i1.source = 'Images\\light\\t.jpg'
            self.manager.screens[0].ids.b1.background_normal = 'Images\\light\\btn.jpg'
            self.manager.screens[0].ids.b2.background_normal = 'Images\\light\\btn.jpg'
            self.manager.screens[0].ids.b3.background_normal = 'Images\\light\\btn.jpg'
            self.manager.screens[0].ids.l1.color = 0,0,0,1
            self.manager.screens[0].ids.b1.color = 0,0,0,1
            self.manager.screens[0].ids.b2.color = 0,0,0,1
            self.manager.screens[0].ids.b3.color = 0, 0, 0, 1

            # Screen 2
            self.ids.i1.source = 'Images\\light\\bg.jpg'
            self.ids.b1.background_normal = 'Images\\light\\btn.jpg'
            self.ids.b2.background_normal = 'Images\\light\\btn.jpg'
            self.ids.s1.background_normal = 'Images\\light\\btn.jpg'
            self.ids.l1.color = 0,0,0,1
            self.ids.l2.color = 0, 0, 0, 1
            self.ids.l3.color = 0, 0, 0, 1
            self.ids.s1.color = 0,0,0,1
            self.ids.b1.color = 0,0,0,1
            self.ids.b2.color = 0, 0, 0, 1





class Screen3(Screen):
    pass

class Screen4(Screen):
    pass
class Screen_Manager(ScreenManager):
    pass
# running the app

kv = Builder.load_file('mom.kv')

class MomApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MomApp().run()
```

## kv file-

```
Screen_Manager:
    Screen1:
    Screen2:
    Screen3:
    Screen4:

<Screen1>:
    name: 's1'
    FloatLayout:

        Image:
            id: i1
            source: 'Images\\Dark\\t.jpg'
            allow_stretch: True


        Label:
            id: l1
            text: 'abcd'
            font_size: 150
            color: 1,1,1,1
            pos_hint:{'y': 0.3}


        Button:
            id: b1
            background_normal: 'Images\\dark\\btn.jpg'
            pos_hint:{'y': 0.3,'x': 0.4}
            text: 'Settings'
            font_size: 40
            color: 1,1,1,1
            size_hint: 0.2,0.1
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: 0,0,1,1
                Line:
                    width: 5
                    rectangle: self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height


            on_release:
                app.root.current = 's2'
                root.manager.transition.direction = 'left'

        Button:
            id: b2
            background_normal: 'Images\\dark\\btn.jpg'
            pos_hint:{'y': 0.45,'x': 0.4}
            text: 'Start'
            font_size: 40
            color: 1,1,1,1
            size_hint: 0.2,0.1
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: 0,0,1,1
                Line:
                    width: 5
                    rectangle: self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height


        Button:
            id: b3
            background_normal: 'Images\\dark\\btn.jpg'
            pos_hint:{'y': 0.947,'x':0.898}
            text: 'Close'
            font_size: 30
            color: 1,1,1,1
            size_hint: 0.1,0.05
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba:  1,0,0,1

                Line:
                    width: 3
                    rectangle: self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height
            on_press:
                App = app.get_running_app()
                App.stop()

<Screen2>:
    name: 's2'
    FloatLayout:
        Image:
            id: i1
            source: 'Images\\dark\\bg.jpg'
            allow_stretch: True

        Label:

            id: l1
            text: 'Settings'
            font_size: 100
            color: 1,1,1,1
            pos_hint: {'y': 0.4}

        Button:
            id: b1
            text: 'Back'
            background_normal: 'Images\\dark\\btn.jpg'
            size_hint: 0.1,0.05
            pos_hint: {'y':0.947,'x':0.002}
            color: 1,1,1,1
            font_size: 30
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: 1,0,0,1
                Line:
                    width: 3
                    rectangle: self.x, self.y, self.width ,self.height
            on_release:
                app.root.current = 's1'
                root.manager.transition.direction = 'right'

        Spinner:
            id: s1
            text: 'Default'
            background_normal: 'Images\\dark\\btn.jpg'
            size_hint: 0.1,0.05
            pos_hint: {'y':0.67,'x':0.2}
            color: 1,1,1,1
            font_size: 30
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: 0,0,1,1
                Line:
                    width: 3
                    rectangle: self.x, self.y, self.width ,self.height
            values: 'Light', 'Dark', 'Default'
            on_text: root.mode(s1.text)

        Label:

            id: l2
            text: 'Theme:'
            font_size: 50
            color: 1,1,1,1
            pos_hint: {'y': 0.2, 'x': -0.42}

        Label:

            id: l3
            text: '___________________________________________________________________________'
            font_size: 50
            color: 1,1,1,1
            pos_hint: {'y': 0.1}

       

        Button:
            id: b2
            background_normal: 'Images\\dark\\btn.jpg'
            pos_hint:{'y': 0.947,'x':0.898}
            text: 'Close'
            font_size: 30
            color: 1,1,1,1
            size_hint: 0.1,0.05
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba:  1,0,0,1

                Line:
                    width: 3
                    rectangle: self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height
            on_press:
                App = app.get_running_app()
                App.stop()
```

so here how do i save the dark mode or light mode so when user opens it next time it stays the way it was.

Comment: Could you provide some code to explain your question?

Comment: Please show the code that failed and the error traceback.

Comment: Sir i dont actually know how to save the changes thats why i could not put those

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you write dark mode and light mode value to a text file something like this

add following line to the `mode` method

```
file1 = open("log.txt","w")
L = [value] 
file1.writelines(L)
file1.close()
```

The above code writes  `value` as `Dark` or `Light` to a text file called 'log.txt'

So The dark mode or Light mode will be saved to the text file.

And While entering the screen use  `on_enter: ()` method and read the text file and get saved value

```
"""
code snippet
"""
class Screen2(Screen):

    def on_enter(self):
        file1 = open("log.txt","r+") 
        value = (file1.read())

        if value == 'Dark' or value == 'Default':
            

            # Screen 1
            self.manager.screens[0].ids.i1.source = 'Images\\dark\\t.jpg'
            self.manager.screens[0].ids.b1.background_normal = 'Images\\dark\\btn.jpg'
            self.manager.screens[0].ids.b2.background_normal = 'Images\\dark\\btn.jpg'
            self.manager.screens[0].ids.b3.background_normal = 'Images\\dark\\btn.jpg'
            self.manager.screens[0].ids.l1.color = 1, 1, 1, 1
            self.manager.screens[0].ids.b1.color = 1, 1, 1, 1
            self.manager.screens[0].ids.b2.color = 1, 1, 1, 1
            self.manager.screens[0].ids.b3.color = 1, 1, 1, 1
            # Screen 2
            self.ids.i1.source = 'Images\\dark\\bg.jpg'
            self.ids.b1.background_normal = 'Images\\dark\\btn.jpg'
            self.ids.b2.background_normal = 'Images\\dark\\btn.jpg'
            self.ids.s1.background_normal = 'Images\\dark\\btn.jpg'
            self.ids.l1.color = 1, 1, 1, 1
            self.ids.l2.color = 1, 1, 1, 1
            self.ids.l3.color = 1, 1, 1, 1
            self.ids.s1.color = 1, 1, 1, 1
            self.ids.b1.color = 1, 1, 1, 1
            self.ids.b2.color = 1, 1, 1, 1


        elif value == 'Light' :
            print('light')
            # Screen 1
            self.manager.screens[0].ids.i1.source = 'Images\\light\\t.jpg'
            self.manager.screens[0].ids.b1.background_normal = 'Images\\light\\btn.jpg'
            self.manager.screens[0].ids.b2.background_normal = 'Images\\light\\btn.jpg'
            self.manager.screens[0].ids.b3.background_normal = 'Images\\light\\btn.jpg'
            self.manager.screens[0].ids.l1.color = 0,0,0,1
            self.manager.screens[0].ids.b1.color = 0,0,0,1
            self.manager.screens[0].ids.b2.color = 0,0,0,1
            self.manager.screens[0].ids.b3.color = 0, 0, 0, 1

            # Screen 2
            self.ids.i1.source = 'Images\\light\\bg.jpg'
            self.ids.b1.background_normal = 'Images\\light\\btn.jpg'
            self.ids.b2.background_normal = 'Images\\light\\btn.jpg'
            self.ids.s1.background_normal = 'Images\\light\\btn.jpg'
            self.ids.l1.color = 0,0,0,1
            self.ids.l2.color = 0, 0, 0, 1
            self.ids.l3.color = 0, 0, 0, 1
            self.ids.s1.color = 0,0,0,1
            self.ids.b1.color = 0,0,0,1
            self.ids.b2.color = 0, 0, 0, 1
```

reference : https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html

Comment: Thank you sir,  I was not able to do that

Comment: That is what you were trying to achieve right?